# Specifying the message in warnings.simple_filter() filters based on category not message

Tags: python, warnings

When we import our_library in Python2, we have coded it to raise a DeprecationWarning once. Here's the representative code.

*our_library/**init**.py*

```
def _py2_deprecation_warning():
    py2_warning = ('Python2 support is deprecated and will be removed in '
                   'a future release. Consider switching to Python3.')
    warnings.filterwarnings('once', message=py2_warning)
    warnings.warn(message=py2_warning,
                  category=DeprecationWarning,
                  stacklevel=3,
                  )


def _python_deprecation_warnings():
    if sys.version_info.major == 2:
        _py2_deprecation_warning()


_python_deprecation_warnings()
```

---

We deprecated the parameters in a function in our_library. Here's the representative code:

*our_library/some_module.py*

```
def some_function(new_param, deprecated_param):
  if deprecated_param:
      param_deprecation_msg = (
          'The parameter "{}" will be removed in a future version of Nilearn.'
          'Please use the parameter "{}" instead.'.format(deprecated_param,
                                                          new_param,
                                                          )
      )
      warnings.warn(category=DeprecationWarning,
                    message=param_deprecation_msg,
                    stacklevel=3)
```

---

Then when we import our library, and call that function, like this:

*calling_script.py*

```
from our_library.some_module import some_function

some_function(deprecated_param)
```

We get the Python2 DeprecationWarning but not the Parameter DeprecationWarning.

```
DeprecationWarning: Python2 support is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider switching to Python3. 
 _python_deprecation_warnings()
```

---

Now know I can solve this by using a `with warnings.catch_warnings():` or `resetwarnings()`. However I thought that specifying the message explicitly in Python2 Warning will prevent the `'once` filter being set for other DeprecationWarnings.

However that is not the case? WhHy is that and how do I make my existing code work without using CatchWarnings or reset warnings?

If I change the Parameter warning to FutureWarning, that I can see.
Why is the first simplefilter blocking all deprecation messages based on category instead of messages?

UPDATE:
`with warnings.catch_warnings():` doesn't seem to work either.

```
def _py2_deprecation_warning():
    py2_warning = ('Python2 support is deprecated and will be removed in '
                   'a future release. Consider switching to Python3.')
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.filterwarnings('once', message=py2_warning)
        warnings.warn(message=py2_warning,
                      category=DeprecationWarning,
                      stacklevel=3,
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had forgotten that DeprecationWarnings are not displayed by defualt. They must specifically be set to be displayed, which I have not done here.